# How to remove trailing characters with Transact-SQL (t-sql)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, delimiter, trailing

With transact-sql (t-sql) I have a string constant and three string variables I want to Concatenate with a semicolon delimiter between each value.  Each of the three string variables are sometimes blank or null, which creates situations where there is one, two, or three semicolon delimiters that I don't want.

I tried Concat_ws() function which is supposed to work according to t-sql websites, but I get error message saying not a recognized function name.  I tried two statements with Replace() function where I replace double or triple semicolons with blanks instead.  That works but seems crude and won't help me replace just one trailing semicolon.  Any ideas?

Sample code that produces too many semicolons when a var is blank:

```
Concat('Label ', ';', var1, ';', var2, ';', var3) as Result
```

Comment: Concat_ws() was added to SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Concat_WS() is  not working for me.  Gives error.  Not sure what version of t-sql i have, it's part of vendor software here.

Comment: `Concat_WS` will skip arguments that are `null`, but not empty strings. You could use a `case` expression (or `iif`) to substitute `null` for empty strings. Tip: `select @@Version;` will return the version of SQL Server.

Comment: Please add the results you get from `SELECT @@VERSION` to your question. Seems you're running a version prior to 2017.

Comment: I will try a case expression or iif.  When i ran select @@Version; error said Must delcare the scalar variable @@Version.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The + string concatenation looked simplest to me so I tried that and it worked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isnull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select
  concat('Label ', isnull(';' + var1, ''), isnull(';' + var2, ''), isnull(';' + var3, '')) as Result
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d97ddcd567f5aff933417d148138e580).
Results:

```
> | Result       |
> | :----------- |
> | Label ;a;b;c |
> | Label ;d;e   |
> | Label ;f;g   |
> | Label ;h;i   |
> | Label ;j     |
> | Label ;k     |
> | Label ;l     |
> | Label        |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an equivalent to `concat_ws()` in SQL Server:

```
stuff( coalesce(';' + nullif(var1, ''), '') + coalesce(';' + nullif(var2, ''), '') + coalesce(';' + nullif(var3, ''), ''), 1, 1, '') as Result
```

You can prepend the `'Label '` to this result.  I'm not sure if you really want a semicolon after `'Label '`, so it wouldn't be appropriate in `concat_ws()` either.

Answer (score 1):

For this you simply need to change `';', @var#` to `';'+@var#` inside your CONCAT statement.

```
DECLARE 
  @var1 VARCHAR(10) = 'abc',
  @var2 VARCHAR(10) = 'xyz',
  @var3 VARCHAR(10) = '123';

SELECT CONCAT('Label ', ';'+@var1, ';'+@var2, ';'+@var3) as Result;
```

Against a table:

```
DECLARE 
  @v1 VARCHAR(10) = 'abc',
  @v2 VARCHAR(10) = 'xyz',
  @v3 VARCHAR(10) = '123';

DECLARE @table TABLE (var1 VARCHAR(10),var2 VARCHAR(10),var3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @table VALUES (@v1,@v2,NULL),(@v1,NULL,NULL),(@v1,NULL,@v3),(NULL,NULL,NULL)

SELECT CONCAT('Label ', ';'+var1, ';'+var2, ';'+var3) as Result
FROM @table;
```

**Results:**

```
Result
---------------------------------------
Label ;abc;xyz
Label ;abc
Label ;abc;123
Label
```

To handle blanks you wrap the var# with NULLIF(var#,''). Final Solution:

```
DECLARE 
  @v1 VARCHAR(10) = 'abc',
  @v2 VARCHAR(10) = 'xyz',
  @v3 VARCHAR(10) = '123';

DECLARE @table TABLE (var1 VARCHAR(10),var2 VARCHAR(10),var3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @table VALUES (@v1,@v2,NULL),(@v1,NULL,NULL),(@v1,NULL,@v3),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
                     (@v1,@v2,''),(@v1,'',''),(@v1,'',@v3),(NULL,'',NULL);

SELECT CONCAT('Label ', ';'+NULLIF(var1,''), ';'+NULLIF(var2,''), ';'+NULLIF(var3,'')) as Result
FROM @table;
```

**Results:**

```
Result
---------------------------------------
Label ;abc;xyz
Label ;abc
Label ;abc;123
Label 
Label ;abc;xyz
Label ;abc
Label ;abc;123
Label
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @VAR1 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @VAR2 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLAR  @VAR3 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @VAR11 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @VAR22 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLAR  @VAR33 VARCHAR(10)

    SET @VAR1 = …
    SET @VAR2 = … 
    SET @VAR3 = … 

IF @VAR1 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @VAR11 = CONCAT(@VAR1,';')
ELSE
SET @VAR11 = ''

IF @VAR2 IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @VAR22 = CONCAT(@VAR2,';')
ELSE
SET @VAR22 = ''

IF @VAR3 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @VAR33 = CONCAT(@VAR2,';')
ELSE 
SET @VAR33 = ''

    Concat('Label ', ';', @var11, @var22, @var33) as Result
```